# Checking User Agent in Wicket

Tags: wicket, user-agent

I am using wicket 1.5 and I am not able to see in the `getClientInfo()` method

```
(WebRequest)RequestCycle.get().getRequest()
```

I saw the other place this code

```
WebClientInfo clientInfo = (WebClientInfo)WebRequestCycle.get().getClientInfo();
```

But I am not able to see any WebRequestCycle in Wicket 1.5.

Any ideas how to check the user agent in Wicket 1.5?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way is to use

```
WebSession.get().getClientInfo().getUserAgent();
```

On newer Wicket Versions (6 or newer), you should use:

```
WebClientInfo clientInfo = new WebClientInfo(getRequestCycle());

System.out.println("Client: " + clientInfo.getUserAgent());
System.out.println("Navigator: " + clientInfo.getProperties().getNavigatorAppName() + ", version " + clientInfo.getProperties().getNavigatorAppVersion()  + ", codName: " + clientInfo.getProperties().getNavigatorAppCodeName() + ", plataform: " + clientInfo.getProperties().getNavigatorPlatform() + ", AppCodName: " + clientInfo.getProperties().getNavigatorAppCodeName());
System.out.println("NavigatorUserAgent: " + clientInfo.getProperties().getNavigatorUserAgent());
System.out.println("Tamanho da tela (Width x Height): " + clientInfo.getProperties().getScreenWidth() + " x "  + clientInfo.getProperties().getScreenHeight() );
```

Comment: Well that would be per Session right ? I was looking for per Request, like writing a RequestMapper in WebApplication and handling the direction which version to be rendered example Desktop or mobile.

Comment: Wicket caches the client info per session, because it is not expected that it will change. if you think it might and you want it per request you can do WebClientInfo info=new WebClientInfo(RequestCycle) whenever you want.

Comment: ok i understand the session will not change, but i dont want to write the same piece of code in every page, how can i control this user agent at the application level ?

Answer (score 2):

You can also do:

```
((WebRequest) getRequest()).getHeader("User-Agent")
```