# Wicket: Get Browser Information

Tags: java, browser, version, wicket

How do I get information about the browser in a Java/Wicket/Maven Project?

Greetings

Comment: When I googled "browser info wicket" the first link gave me the answer? https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Getting+Browser+Information. Is this, the information what you need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can capture the browser information using the following code

> getApplication().getRequestCycleSettings().setGatherExtendedBrowserInfo(true);
>
> WebClientInfo w = (WebClientInfo)getWebRequestCycle().getClientInfo();
>   ClientProperties cp = w.getProperties();
>
> // do something with the data
>   cp.getNavigatorAppName();
>   cp.getNavigatorAppCodeName();
>   cp.getNavigatorAppVersion();
>   cp.getBrowserVersionMajor();
>   cp.getBrowserVersionMinor();

Exerpt taken from [WICKET Documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Getting+Browser+Information)

**EDIT** 
   Updated from comments. 
   *The above code is for Wicket 1.4.x. For newer versions of Wicket replace getWebRequestCycle() with getRequestCycle()*

Comment: This is for Wicket 1.4.x. For newer versions of Wicket replace `getWebRequestCycle()` with `getRequestCycle()`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! 
We are using Wicket 6 - but if I replace getWebRequestCycle() with getRequestCycle() Netbeans says that there is no such method

Answer (score 3):

If there is no `getClientInfo()` on `getRequestCycle()` (like there wasn't for me either), you could try the answer to this question:

[Checking User Agent in Wicket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10728787/checking-user-agent-in-wicket)

```
WebSession.get().getClientInfo();
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Wicket 6.x also provides `org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxClientInfoBehavior`. A demo of it can be seen at: http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples-6.0.x/ajaxhellobrowser/